# Attempting to make my program automatically tab to next input field (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently making a program which requires the input of a field which is made up of several components. I have broken them down into their unique parts, and I want to make my code work such that when the user has input the required characters it automatically moves such that they are writing the rest of the code in the following text box.

My code so far is:

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 2)
            textBox2.Select();
            textBox2.Focus();


        if (textBox2.Text.Length == 3)
            textBox3.Select();
            textBox3.Focus();

        if (textBox3.Text.Length == 2)
            textBox4.Select();
            textBox4.Focus();

    }
```

I'm sure I probably have this in the wrong location, but I am new to C# and hence a massive newb. Any help would be greatly appreciated because at the moment this isn't working and it is massively annoying.

Comment: Please tag the correct platform (windows forms or wpf). To answer your question you need to hook your text boxes to an input event, check the value, and then change focus if necessary.

Comment: The platform is a windows form

Comment: In addition to @Berkay's answer, you might want to set `tabIndex` property in required order: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd16a8cw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Please, mark the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you call this on Form's constructor, it won't do anything, when Form the constructor works the length of all textboxes are 0. You need some events like textbox's `TextChanged`. Because you need to focus next textbox, after some text has written. So something like this,

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length == 4)
            {
                textBox2.Focus();
            }
            ...
        }
```

Hope helps,